# Ohm and Mits Age and Tall Math

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. Two Year ago Ohm was 25% shorter than Mits.

   Since Ohm has grown 20% taller, and Mits has grown 4 cm taller.

   Now Mits is 20% taller than Ohm. How many centimeters ohm now?
2. In four years Omits will be twice as old as Ohm. Four years after that, Mits will be

   Twice as old as Omits.Four years after that Mits will be three times as old as Ohm.

   How many years Mits now?

Comment: What have you tried?  Define variables and write equations that capture what you know.  Then solve them.

Comment: i can't get the equation and i get confused :(

Answer (score 1):

Hint for 1:  Let $P$ be Ohm's height two years ago and $M$ be Mits' height two years ago.  Write an equation that captures the first sentence: $P=0.75M$  How tall is Ohm today in terms of $P$?  How tall is Mits today in terms of $M$?  Now write an equation that captures the second and third sentences.  You have two equations in two unknowns.